# Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.internal.bn$b'

Tags: android, google-play-games

I am integrating google play game services in my android game but I am getting this error:

> Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.internal.bn$b',
>   referenced from method com.google.android.gms.internal.bn.a

I am following this link:

https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init

Whenever I try to use the signInButton class

```
findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
```

The game gets crashed with fatal exception.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(19802): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 06-26 13:18:44.790:
E/AndroidRuntime(19802): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start  activity
ComponentInfo{com.app.fly/com.app.fly.SimpleGame}:
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I am unable to trace the error.Please help.

Comment: I am still waiting for the solution.This error is irritating me.

Answer (score 1):

I really need more information to be able to help - e.g more of the trace where it gives details of the NullPointerException and more of your code.

However based on the information you have provided, it looks like you may not have defined BaseGameUtils as a LIBRARY project  AND/OR you may not have not included it as a REFERENCE project in your library. The reason why I am thinking this is:  it looks as though you are crashing as soon as you try to execute your first call to Google Play Game Services code i.e it looks as though ALL the Google code is missing from your package.

A good approach that many people have used is to get the Google Sample Project working first. Details here:

https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples/blob/master/README.md

and this may also help:

[Google Play Game Services leaderboard - Unable to set jars up correctly in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16887589/google-play-game-services-leaderboard-unable-to-set-jars-up-correctly-in-eclip/16888232#16888232)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the same problem described in [Google Drive API doesn't play well with ProGuard (NPE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410520/google-drive-api-doesnt-play-well-with-proguard-npe), which has an answer.