# importing google play service reference to my map project

Tags: android, google-maps

I Have a Android Map Project in Eclipse and Testing It Now debug Mode.Problem is that I am trying to add Google Play Service Reference to My Project.When i try import this `Existing Code Into Work space` from Eclipse and I Choose the Android SDK path Where Play Service is Installed and Press OK the I Show The Red Exclamation Sign On my Project.Is there any One Know What May Be the Issue and Any Other Right Way to add reference of Library. Plz Help

Comment: You need to give us more info on what error Eclipse is showing.

Comment: `Description Resource Path Location Type
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'D:\android\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\bin\google-play-services_lib.jar' Track  Build path Build Path Problem
` This Is Showing In Problems

Comment: It can't find the jar, because it doesn't have a jar.  It's an android library, and you need to include it as a library.

Comment: Sir I Updated My SDK and There is Path For This In `Extras` Folder of SDk But `google-play-services_lib.jar` is missing there i also Deleted the and reinstalled but file is Not Showing There

Comment: what may b the issue plz guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google BaseGameUtils should be defined as a LIBRARY project and you should add it as a REFERENCE in your project.

Please see the guide provided by Google at: https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples/blob/master/README.md which I found to be reasonably accurate.

This may also help:

[Google Play Game Services leaderboard - Unable to set jars up correctly in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16887589/google-play-game-services-leaderboard-unable-to-set-jars-up-correctly-in-eclip)

Good Luck !